# C++ Non-Class member compile error in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, roguelike

I am attempting to follow the tutorial found [here](http://www.kathekonta.com/rlguide/article1.html) to learn the basic idea behind programming roguelike game. I am using Code::Blocks 10.05 running portable from my usb and compiling with MinGW. Console.h also came from the website I linked above.

I have hit a road block when I have attempted to set up just this class to ensure everything is working:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include "Console.h"

int main( void )
{
    console.Clear();
    return 0;
}
```

When I attempt to use the I get the following error:

> Error: request for member 'Clear' in 'console', which is of non-class type 'Win32Console()'|

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**Edit**

I reinstalled MinGW and Code::Blocks after promptly ruining them for myself and am now back with the error:

> undefined reference to `Win32Console::Win32Console()

Comment: I downloaded the header and it all looked fine. Win32Console is definitely a class. What compiler are you using?

Comment: That compiles cleanly for me. Your error suggests `console` is a function, though, such as `Win32Console console();`. Look in the header and make sure it's `Win32Console console;`.

Comment: What did you change when it was giving you an undefined reference? That meant it compiled before, and isn't now, so something you changed should be causing this.

Comment: I haven't changed anything that's what is confusing me.  I have linked the library and added the header to the project but only that line gives me the error

Answer (score 0):

before adding the header file, paste this line: `#define _WIN32`. Its possible that the _WIN32 isn't defined?